# Testing - set declined card to a customer

Tags: node.js, testing, stripe-payments

I want to update a customer with a declined card for testing purposes.

But if I do:

```
Stripe.customers.update(stripeCustomer.id, {
    source: 'tok_chargeDeclined', // Token provided by stripe of a declined card
});
```

I get an exception:

> Exception while invoking method 'stripe.test' { Error: Your card was
>   declined.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attach a card to a customer(for example with that update call), Stripe makes a temporary $0 charge against the card, to validate it and ensure you can charge the customer successfully later. This is mentioned at https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards#saving-credit-card-details-for-later.

When you attach `tok_chargeDeclined`, this charge is declined and the card is not added to the customer. To test the case where a card can be successfully added to a customer, but declined later(i.e. if it later expires or has no funds), you can use the `tok_chargeCustomerFail` card from https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses